# Generics type casting

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I just don't get something in the .NET generic type casting.
Can someone explain what happens in the following code snippet?

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<int> ints = new List<int>();
    IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();

    var rez1=(IEnumerable<object>)ints; //runtime error
    var rez2=(IEnumerable<object>)strings; //works
    var rez3=(List<object>)strings; //runtime error
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's start with the second line which is easiest.

That cast works because the type parameter of [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) is now [*covariant*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx#InterfaceCovariantTypeParameters) (that's what the `out` in `out T` does). This means you can cast an `IEnumerable<Derived>` to an `IEnumerable<Base>` freely.

The first line, which would seem to be the same case, does not work because `int` is a value type. Interface variance does not work with value types at all because value types do not really inherit from `System.Object`; they can be *boxed* into an `object`, but that's not the same. The documentation mentions that

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type
>   for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the
>   resulting constructed type.

Finally, the third line does not work because the type parameter of [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is *invariant*. You can see there is no `out` on its type parameter; the rules disallow that because `List<T>` is not an interface:

> In the .NET Framework 4, variant type parameters are restricted to
>   generic interface and generic delegate types.

Comment: But Int32 can be cast to Object. Isn't that sufficient to make a covariance? Or it is a compiler feature?

Comment: @Vasaka: That's a boxing operation and not a reference conversion. It's technical, but despite the identical syntax what the compiler actually does in each case is totally different.

Comment: ... as are the type parameters of all generic classes and structs; type variance being supported only for interface and delegate types.

Comment: @Vasaka the link in my answer explains why `(object)1` doesn't count as "assignment compatible" but `(object)"Hello"` does.

Comment: @Vasaka the first post was the wrong one; I meant to refer you to this one on "Inheritance and Representation": http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/19/inheritance-and-representation.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is because interface covariance only works with reference types.  Int32, of course, is a value type.

This gives more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx

And so does this: http://ericlippert.com/2011/09/19/inheritance-and-representation/

Answer (score 0):

The definition of every type which derives from `System.ValueType`, with the exception of `System.Enum`, actually defines two kinds of things: a heap object type, and a storage-location type.  Instances of the latter may be implicitly converted to the former (making a copy of the data contained therein), and instances of the former may be explicitly typecast to the latter (likewise); even though both kinds of things are described by the same `System.Type`, and although they have the same members, they behave very differently.

A `List<AnyClassType>` will expect to hold a bunch of heap-object references; whether the list in question is a `List<String>`, `List<StringBuilder>`, `List<Button>`, or whatever, may be of interest to users of the list, but isn't really of interest to the `List<T>` itself.  If one casts a `List<Button>` to an `IEnumerable<Control>`, someone who calls its `GetEnumerator()` method will expect to get an object which will output references to heap objects that derive from `Control`; the return from `List<Button>.GetEnumerator()` will satisfy that expectation.  By contrast, if someone were to cast a `List<Int32>` to `List<Object>`, someone who called `GetEnumerator()` would expect something that would output heap object references, but `List<Integer>.GetEnumerator` will instead yield something that outputs value-type integers.

It's possible to store `Int32` values into a `List<Object>` or a `List<ValueType>`; storing an integer to such a list will convert it to its heap object form and store a reference to it; calling `GetEnumerator()` would yield something that outputs heap references.  There is no way to specify, however, that such a list will only contain instances of the heap type corresponding to `Int32`.  In C++/CLI, it's possible to declare variables of type "reference to heap-stored valuetype", but the mechanisms behind generic types in .net cannot work with such types.